# How to use negative lookbehind with quantifiers?

Tags: regex, perl

I want to use negative lookbehind with quantifiers. But I have the error. I use Perl.

I have several text files and I need to detect that they have special text prefix before the distinct word.

Error:

> A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width

My regular expression:

```
/(?<!big([\s]+)?)dog/
```

I want to get the fourth and fifth number.

```
1. bigdog - not ok
2. big   dog - not ok
3. big dog - not ok
4. dog - ok
5. dog any text except big.  dog - ok
```

Comment: (OT: Unless you’re using the capturing group in `([\s]+)?` it could be shortened to `\s*`.)

Comment: You've abstracted away too much to give a proper answer.

Comment: What do you mean? I think that example is okay @ikegami

Comment: That's because it's very likely that you already decided on poor approach to solve the problem, and presented the problem in terms that would be solved by that approach. This will invariable lead to poor answers. If were knew what you were [actually doing](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341), we could provide better answers.

Comment: ...Except no, the OP said in a comment below that they are really looking for two natural-language words in a natural-language sentence. I'll leave my previous comment as a cautionary note, but it doesn't appear to apply in this circumstance.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the SKIP and FAIL verbs.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Test::More tests => 7;

my $regex = qr/big\s*dog(*SKIP)(?!)|dog/;

unlike 'bigdog',    $regex;
unlike 'big dog',   $regex;
unlike 'big   dog', $regex;
unlike 'cat',       $regex;

like 'dog',       $regex;
like 'small dog', $regex;
like 'medium dog and big dog', $regex;
```

`qr/(?<!big)\s*dog/` is problematic as

```
big dog
    ^
    |
matches here: is not preceded by "big" but "big "
```

Answer (score 5):

For the problem as specified, you could use any of the following:

```
/(?<!big)(?<!\s)\s*dog/
```

or

```
/
   ^
   (?: big \s* dog
   |   (?! big \s* dog ) .
   )*
   dog
/xs
```

or

```
/
   (?: (?:^|[^b]) ig
   |   (?:^|[^i]) g
   |   (?:^|[^g\s])
   )
   \s* dog
/x
```

or

```
s/big\s*dog/!/rg =~ /dog/
```

or

```
reverse($_) =~ /god(?!\s*gib)/
```

I gave many alternatives because not one is particularly good. Better solutions probably exist in practice, but that requires knowing the [actual problem](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341) that needs solving.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I can try to explain in more detail. I have several text files and I need to detect that they have special text prefix before the distinct word. @ikegami

Comment: And both the prefix and the word are English words found in an English sentence?

Comment: Yes, like this)

Comment: Ah ok, I stand corrected :) Usually, when we get this kind of questions, it's really about extracting data from XML or something.

Comment: I should say that I have template toolkit file. I want to use an only regular expression for solving. Sorry if I misled you. @ikegami

Comment: First option worked pretty well for me. Thanks!